# Page margin from second page in wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

First page

In my pdf the header on the first page should have no offset. So the margin from the top is zero.

Second and following pages

I want to set a top margin for the second page and the following pages.

So for this i have created header which is hide on first page but after showing header body content get cut.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem while putting header and footer.
I just set footer-spacing and header-spacing in the options before generate PDF.
That works fine for me.